# SQL Server 2005 not collecting logins in the log file

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, error-log

I am currently running SQL Server 2005 Standard Edition on a Windows 2003 server machine.

I have gone to the properties of the server and confirmed that the `Login Auditing` is set to both failed and successful logins. For some reason though there is nothing in the logins for fails or successes in the SQL Server logs when I know there have been logins for both.

I have searched out the reason for this and have not been able to come up with anything helpful, so I am hoping that someone here could give me a little direction. This is working on my other SQL Servers, so I know where to look for the results, but there are none there.

Comment: As this is not actually a programming question, you would be better off asking it in http://dba.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After speaking with Microsoft about the issue and doing much research, it was determined that this was an issue with the particular version of SQL (SQL Server 2005 Service Pack 2 9.00.3042) running on that particular version of the windows release.  We reinstalled SQL, and then did all the updates and patches to both windows and SQL and this seems to have resolved the issue.  The SQL logs are now tracking both success and failed logins.